# Is $R_1 \oplus 0$ a free $R_1 \oplus R_2$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $R_1$ and $R_2$ are unital rings.  Consider $R_1 \oplus \{0\}$ an $R_1 \oplus R_2$-module.  Is this a free module?

I am thinking it's not, since there are relations. How can I take this idea further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly not, since it has a non-zero annihilator: $\{0\}\times R_2$.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually just found out that result.  I am pretty new to module theory; is there a way to show  nontrivial annihilator $\implies$ not free using only the definition of a free module as one with a basis?

Comment: Here it is simple: as it's a cyclic module; i. e. a quotient of $R_1\times R_2$ by a non-zero ideal, generated by $\overline{(1,0)}$, which is killed by any $(0,r_2)$.

Comment: Unless $R_2 = 0$. :)

Comment: Yes. Impilcitly, I consider rings with $1$.

Comment: @Bernard $\{0\}$ *is* a ring with identity! `;-)`. By the way, over rings without an identity, the notion of free module doesn't make much sense: even the ring itself has no basis.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is actually an  ideal of a ring: in the commutative case it is a free module iff it is principal and  the  generating element is not a zero-divisor. In your case it is principal being generated by $(1,0)$ but is n a zero divisor as pointed out by Bernard, and hence not free.